# git clone only README and git files, not actual project work

Tags: git, github

Goal: clone repo and all of it's project contents and branches

I cloned using URL and had to setup both an SSH Key and PAT.

Bash Terminal:

```sh
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project$ git clone https://github.com/project/synthetic-data-gen.git
Cloning into 'synthetic-data-gen'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 178, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (178/178), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (125/125), done.
remote: Total 178 (delta 67), reused 152 (delta 44), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (178/178), 1.40 MiB | 1.04 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (67/67), done.
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project$ ls
synthetic-data-gen
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project$ ls synthetic-data-gen/
README.md
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project$ git branch
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /mnt)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project$ git pull
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /mnt)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project$ git checkout --track -b development origin/development
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /mnt)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Comment: heu, you miss the changedir, don't you ? `cd synthetic-data-gen`

Comment: I do ! haha. Thanks man :) Please post as answer and I will accept when it next allows me to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be into the cloned directory before doing git command

```
cd synthetic-data-gen
```